# how do i get ajax contents in global javascript variable

Tags: ajax

i want to put the contents in javascript globaly defined variable, The content i have obtained using ajax call .

http://pastebin.com/TqiJx3PA

thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pastebin code already does this. I'm guessing that the problem you're actually facing exists because your ajax call is **asynchronous**, which means that you're making the ajax request (asynchronously), and immediately trying to access the value in the global variable - but it hasn't been set yet.

The solution to this is to execute your post-ajax code in the `onReadyStateChange` callback.

```
function handleResponse(result_cont) {
    // your result_cont processing code here
}

ajax(handleResponse);

function ajax(callback) {
    var xmlHttp;
    try { // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
        // Internet Explorer
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
            if (xmlHttp.responseText != "") {
                result_cont = xmlHttp.responseText
                alert(result_cont);

                // ############# here's the important change #############
                // execute the provided callback
                callback(result_cont);
            }
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "contentdetails.php?cid=1", true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```