# String variable passed from a function to a function name does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal

I am trying to use the value of a drop list as the the name of the next function. The string is correct and shows in an alert. Also writing the name explicitly in the code does work. But using parts from the variable in the scope of both functions does not work at all.

```
    Drupal.behaviors.smart_inventory = {
attach: function(context, settings) {

  // this should be in the scope of both functions
  var selecttype;

  $('#select-voc-content_types', context).change(function () {

          contenttype = $( this ).val();
          secondary = $('#' + contenttype);

          if($(secondary).length > 0)
          {
              // set the select list. tried an alert and the variable string is set 
              selecttype = '#select-voc-' + $( this ).val();

              $('.group-types').show();
              $('#' + contenttype).show();
              $('#object-ajax-form').hide();                      
          }
          else
          {
              $('#object-node-form-message').show();
              $.post('smart_inventory/ajax', { "node-type": contenttype }, frmDrupal);
          }

  });

  // this does not respond as jquery does not accept the string as an element name
  // or maybe the variable is not available here?

  $( selecttype, context ).change(function () {

          var nodetype = $( this ).val();
          $('#object-node-form-message').show();
          $.post('smart_inventory/ajax', { "node-type": nodetype }, frmDrupal);

  });

  var frmDrupal = function(responseText) {

      $('#object-ajax-form').show();
      $('#object-ajax-form').html(responseText);
      $('#object-node-form-message').hide();
  }
}
```

};

If found that this works! But is nesting a function good practice? or good enough? ;

```
    Drupal.behaviors.smart_inventory = {
attach: function(context, settings) {

  var selecttype;

  $('#select-voc-content_types', context).change(function (selecttype) {

          contenttype = $( this ).val();
          secondary = $('#' + contenttype);

          if($(secondary).length > 0)
          {
              // set the select list 
              selecttype = '#select-voc-' + $( this ).val();

              $('.group-types').show();
              $('#' + contenttype).show();
              $('#object-ajax-form').hide();                      
          }
          else
          {
              $('#object-node-form-message').show();
              $.post('smart_inventory/ajax', { "node-type": contenttype }, frmDrupal);
          }
          $( selecttype , context ).change(function () {
               var nodetype = $( this ).val();
               $('#object-node-form-message').show();
               $.post('smart_inventory/ajax', { "node-type": nodetype }, frmDrupal);
          });
```

});

Comment: @tvanfossen , using [id^="select-voc-"] cause a scan of the DOM and triggers a call to the function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972303/how-do-i-get-ajax-contents-in-global-javascript-variable and many others

Comment: be very careful you don't start double registering events.

Answer (score 0):

Your `selecttype` variable is not even set yet when you try to use it - it will only get set when the change handler on the element with id `select-voc-content_types` is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the variable doesn't have a value at the time that the handler is attached.  The easiest way to handle it is using the attribute "starts with" selector to match all possible select types rather than trying to apply a handler per select type.  You could then use the chosen select type to filter within the handler as needed.

```
$('[id^="select-voc-"]',context).change( function() {
       if (this.id == selecttype) {
          ...
       }
       else {
          return false; // this isn't the correct select type, prevent the action
       }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//selecttype changes during an event fire. event registration happens way before then. just do this.
  $( '[id^="select-voc-"]', context ).change(function () {

          var nodetype = $( this ).val();
          $('#object-node-form-message').show();
          $.post('smart_inventory/ajax', { "node-type": nodetype }, frmDrupal);

  });


// depending on your version of jQuery, go for .on wherever possible:

$(context).on({
 'change':function(evt){
   var nodetype = $( this ).val();
              $('#object-node-form-message').show();
              $.post('smart_inventory/ajax', { "node-type": nodetype }, frmDrupal)}
},'[id^="select-voc-"]','');
```