# Can we able to assign the returning data to a variable , which is getting through ajax function?

Tags: jquery

Following is the function that i am using.

Can we able to assign like this?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function validation(){

    var flag

    $.ajax({
      url: 'ajax/test.php',
      success: function(data) {

       flag =data;

      }
    });

    alert(flag);

    }


    </script>
```

Comment: it's [**ASYNCHRONOUS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))!

Comment: Now let's find the best duplicate.

Comment: I very rarely vote down, but I am close to doing so here. @dystroy you have a point!

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do i get ajax contents in global javascript variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972303/how-do-i-get-ajax-contents-in-global-javascript-variable)

Answer (score 1):

The assignation doesn't make problem, but you're calling alert before the asynchronous ajax call has returned, so your alerting `undefined`.

You must do this :

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.php',
  success: function(data) {
     alert(data);
  }
});
```

If you need flag in another function, you must ensure this function isn't called before the ajax call is done. You may do this :

```
var flag;
function otherFunction() {
    alert(flag);
}  
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.php',
  success: function(data) {
     flag = data;
     otherFunction();
  }
});
```

One of the most basic things you need to understand in javascript is that you **must** accommodate its **asynchronous** nature.

You do so by providing callbacks as

- event handlers
- success or error handling functions for all resource fetching functions

Note that this is much simpler than managing yourself a main loop or many threads...

Comment: but i need to get the resulting value into the variable 'flag'.So that i can use it for another function

Comment: Call the function from within the `success` block of the `.ajax()` call and you can pass `data` to it!

Comment: I hope nobody will mention as answer the parameter you can technically set to false...

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about, but you know you can always set `async:false` in your ajax function to solve all the problems you ever had with ajax. Actually just setting it globally would be an excellent idea ?

Comment: @adeneo Thanks for the good laugh. Now let's just hope you didn't make one developer start a whole new permanently blocked web application...